# can not add any other files in addition to DLLs into my MSI build nant file

Tags: nant

**The following codes work**

But this codes gives an error: BUILD FAILED - NESTED BUILD FAILED -Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
<component keepsubdirs="true" name="C__WebConfig" 
id="{E2FDCB8C-64AB-4E0A-9FF5-CAF4B940562B}" 

attr="0" directory="TARGETDIR" feature="F__WebConfig">

<key file="Web.config" />
<fileset basedir="${Source.Dir}">
<include name="Web.config" />
</fileset>
</component>
```

Note:
web.config file or any file will not be added to MSI - please help

Comment: Your MSI and NANT script are no way related. They are 2 different things. What are you using to create the MSI?